# How to avoid serialization of services

Tags: spring, session, serialization, redis, autowired

I'm trying to migrate my application to work with org.redisson.tomcat.RedissonSessionManager to run multiple instances parallel.

Now redis tries to serialize my view-scoped handlers which is totally ok, but it also tries to serialize my @Autowired-services.

```
@Autowired
private ProductService productService;

@Autowired
private TaskExecutor taskExecutor;
```

I think I could make them transient. But how can I make spring to re-autowire them after redis has de-serialized them on an other instance?

Or is there another good pattern how to migrate good old spring-web applications to work with serialized sessions?